# Why does my game’s framerate suddenly drop in release build?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Engine: Cocos2D
Test Hardware:iPhone 4
SDK:3.2.5 final

FPS is stable on 60 in DEBUG & RELEASE mode when we test our game in SIMULATOR. When change our test method from SIMULATOR to DEVICE, a real iPhone 4, game shows no low FPS under DEBUG mode. BUT things go crazy when change to RELEASE mode. FPS goes extremely lower than all situations I describe before. FPS sharply drops from 60 to 20~30.

Don't confuse, in one sentence:FPS drops sharply from 60 to 30 around in RELEASE mode based on real iPhone 4 test.

Any one has any idea on how to handle this? Thanks for all kinds of aids.

Matt

Comment: done by checking "build active architecture only" in our building setting, further indirectly side effects are unforeseeable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is to check the differences between your debug and release build settings. [Thumb code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460378) comes to mind, don’t know if that still applies.

Comment: done by checking "build active architecture only" in our building setting, further indirectly side effects are unforeseeable though.